# Fast Viewer for Large SVG Files?

Tags: image-viewer, svg

I am looking for an SVG viewer that is fast for large SVGs. I have a large SVG that is the output of `dot` for a large graph, which I would like to view. As well as being fast, I'd ideally like it to:

a) Support smoothly zooming out, with no limit on how far you can zoom out

b) Support ctrl/cmd+f for finding text within the SVG

c) Run on mac or linux

Any suggestions?

Comment: What viewer have you already tested that turned out not to be usable for your case? What is in your opinion a "large SVG file" - determined by file size or number of elements,... and how large is large?

Comment: I've tried the chrome and firefox built in viewers. While not unreasonably slow, they do not allow unlimited zoom.

Answer (score 2):

When converting a `dot` file to `svg` the file becomes larger.

- *Convert dot to svg via Graphviz*

  dot -Tsvg filename.dot -o filename.svg

  *635 kB (dot file) ---> 5,9 MB (svg file)*

Maybe you should try working directly with the `dot` file. Or optimize the `svg` if it's too large for Inkscape.

## [SVG Optimizer](https://github.com/svg/svgo).

## Dot Viewer - Linux

```
apt install xdot
```

[image: Dot Viewer]

Not sure if it works for large files.

- [x] Zoom
- [x] Search (but no replace)
- [x] Linux

## [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)

I've tested with [large SVG files from Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Large_SVG_files).

36,6 MB ---> OK (Dual Core, 8 GB RAM) ; 101,0 MB ---> slow

- [x] [Zoom Tool - FLOSS Manuals](http://write.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/zoom-tool/)
- [x] Search (I prefer the search in Dot Viewer) and replace
- [x] Gnu/Linux, MacOS and Windows